# Power of prime number in $n!$ - prove this formula

Tags: number-theory

How to prove:

for $ l := \max\{i \in \mathbb{N}_0 : p^i \mid n!\} $ it holds:

a) $l = \sum_{i=1}^\infty [\frac{n}{p^i}]$

b) $l \leq [ \frac{n}{p-1} ]$

?

If I take a closer look at the sum in a) I see that l must be of the form:

$ l = [\frac{n}{p^1}] + [\frac{n}{p^2}] + ... = A_1 + A_2$.

So I have $ A_j := | \{k, 1 \leq k \leq n : p^j|n\} | = [\frac{n}{p^j}]$ right?

Then $A_1$ gives the quantity of how often $p^1$ is a divisor of n.
Then $A_2$ gives the quantity of how often $p^2$ is a divisor of n.

This is what I got so far.

b) Here I have no idea so far =/

Comment: By the way, part a) is sometimes called Legendre's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have dealt correctly with (a).

As to (b), I believe it's just a matter of computing the sum of a geometric series
$$
l = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \right\rfloor
\le
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{n}{p^i} = n \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p^i} = \dots
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are rght that $A_i$ counts the number of factors in the product defining $n!$ that are divisible by $p^i$. Thus if we consider a specific factor $1\le k\le n$ and write it as $p^rs$ with $s$ not divisible by $p$, then this $k$ is counted in $A_1$ and in $A_2$ and so on up to $A_r$. Hence $k$ is counted exactly $r$ times and contributes exactly $r$ to $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lfloor \frac n{p^i}\rfloor$, just as it should.